# Troubles Checking Radio Button with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have the following code:

```
<input type="radio" id="si" name="new-car" value="S" class="action-key ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
<label for="si" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">Si</span></label>
```

And I'm trying to click it using Selenium. I have tried with Selenium functions and it is not working and now I'm trying with:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('si').checked = true;")
```

But no luck either... Any thoughts? thx

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='si']").click()
```

This did the trick and is working. Thank you anyways :)